# SQL Server - Trigger on insert with counter

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, triggers

I have the following two tables:

- `ITEMS` (ID | CODE | NAME): items are added to the table items and is assigned a new code based on the counters table
- `COUNTERS` (ID | YEAR | COUNTER): there is a line for each year, every year a new line is added and the counter is set to zero.

I would like to increment the current year's counter at every insert of a new item and assign the formatted counter at the code column of the current item.

Example:

- A new item is inserted: `ID=34, CODE=null, NAME=productName`
- The counter of the current year is incremented: `ID=1, YEAR=2019, COUNTER=34`
- The counter value is assigned to the code column : `ID=34, CODE=CE201934, NAME=productName`

How can I create a trigger that perform this task? The trigger has to add a new line on the counter table if the current year change.

Comment: I think you can create trigger on insert to table ITEMS. In that you have to check if COUNTERS exists for this year otherwise insert this and update counters. I thinks better way to use counter was use of sequence. 

For triggers use this documentations : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What happens when an item is deleted? And think carefully about your generation logic. You chose to store this value as a string. How will it be used? Do you intend to compare or sort based on these values. Because item #2 will be CE20192 and item #1000 will be CE20191000. If you sort them, which one comes first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO ITEMS(ID,CODE,NAME)
    VALUES(34,NULL,'ProductName')

    DECLARE @ID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Counters WHERE ID = @ID AND [Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Counters
    (
       ID
       ,Year
       ,Counter
    )
    VALUES(@ID,YEAR(GETDATE()),SELECT MAX(Counter)+1 FROM Counters WHERE ID = @ID AND [Year] = YEAR(GETDATE()))
    END

DECLARE @Code BIGINT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

UPDATE ITEMS
SET Code = @Code
WHERE ID = @ID
```